# How is the output 47?

Tags: turbo-c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>   
#define FIRST_PART 7
#define LAST_PART 5
#define ALL_PARTS FIRST_PART+LAST_PART
 int main() 
 {
    printf ("The Square root of all parts is %d", ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS) ;
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

In the above code the FIRST_PART is defined as 7

LAST_PART is defined as 5

and ALL_PARTS is initialized as FIRST_PART+LAST_PART (which is ideally 12)

but when i am printing ALL_PARTS * ALL_PARTS is giving me 47 as the output!(But i thought answer would be 144)

Please can anyone explain me how ?

Comment: 7+5*7+5 is 47, so why wouldn't you expect that answer? (HINT: if performing calculations as part of a macro, wrap in parenthesis)

Comment: it should be 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be 47

```
FIRST_PART + LAST_PART * FIRST_PART + LAST_PART

MULTIPLICATION HAS MORE PRECEDENCE

SO 7 + 5 * 7 + 5

 7 + 35 + 5

47
```

Comment: hope it will help you

Comment: Value of ALL_PARTS should be 12*12 ?

Comment: Thanx for the help @Tijo John

Comment: You are welcome @Mihir Mehta if it useful mark as right answer